# Ionic running on ios, toolbar not fixed to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

my code: (i tried to change all navbars for toolbars, and also tried adding fixed attribute to the toolbars, and no luck). any page i scroll down in my iphone, the toolbar scrolls as well, and it doesn't happen in my android.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar
    color="danger"
    hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <div *ngIf="checkVacio()" id="cartaInicial">
      <img src="assets/images/lista.png" id="imagenInicial">
      <p id="parrafo" >Para crear una lista solo debes <br> presionar el boton rojo</p>
  </div>

 <ion-list  no-lines>
   <ion-item id="items"
             *ngFor="let lista of Listas"
             [navPush]="listaTerminada"
             [navParams]="lista"
             >{{lista.listaNombre}}
     <p>{{lista.nombre}}</p>
     <button ion-button icon-only
             item-end clear color="danger"
             (click)="onDelete(lista.listaNombre)"
     ><ion-icon name="md-close"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


  <ion-fab bottom right>
    <button  ion-fab mini
             color="danger"
             [navPush]="cadenasMercadosPage">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this in your config.xml in order to avoid page from scrolling:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: But almost all pages do scroll, i just want to stop the toolbar from scrolling, will this prevent only the toolbar? Thanks @Ernesto

Comment: Yes, it should prevent unnecessary scroll to happen.

Comment: It may work, but I must say this is not the user experience that many of the iOS users will expect from your app. They expect the pages to _overscroll_ (like in any other iOS app) so your app _would not feel like native_ with that configuration.